# Benford's law test function inside groupby.agg

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small sample of my dataframe which is 25000 odd rows long:

```
 In [58]: df
 Out[58]:
 Send_Agent  Send_Amount
0      ADR000264   361.940000
1      ADR000264    12.930000
2      ADR000264    11.630000
3      ADR000264    12.930000
4      ADR000264    64.630000
5      ADR000264    12.930000
6      ADR000264    77.560000
7      ADR000264   145.010000
8      API185805   112.34
9      API185805   56.45
10     API185805   48.97
11     API185805   85.44
12     API185805   94.33
13     API185805   116.45
```

There are 2 Send_Agents ADR000264 and API185805. I am trying to apply Benford's law test to the Send_Amount. I am succesfully able to do it when I try for all the Send_Amount irrespective of the Send_Agent. Below is my function to extract the leading digit.

```
def leading_digit(x,dig=1):
    x = str(x)
    out = int(x[dig-1])
    return out
```

This function, when applied to the Send_Amount column, works just fine:

```
  In [75]: df['Send_Amount'].apply(leading_digit)
  Out[75]:
   0        3
   1        1
   2        1
   3        1
   4        6
   5        1
   6        7
   7        1
   8        1
```

It gives an output that is a series and extracts the leading digits from the Send_Amount column.

But when I try the same function after grouping by Send_Agent, I get erroneous results:

```
In [74]: df['Send_Amount'].groupby(df['Send_Agent']).apply(leading_digit)
Out[74]:
Send_Agent
ADR000264    0
API185805    6
dtype: int64
```

Same with groupby.agg

```
In [59]: grouped = df.groupby('Send_Agent')
In [60]: a = grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':leading_digit})

In [61]: a
Out[61]:
                  Send_Amount
     Send_Agent
     ADR000264             0
     API185805             6
```

Edit:

So , now we have the counts of the leading digit.

```
   In [16]: result = df.assign(Leading_Digit =    df['Send_Amount'].astype(str).str[0]).groupby('Send_Agent')['Leading_Digit'].value_counts(sort=False)

In [17]: result
Out[17]:
 Send_Agent         Leading_Digit
 ADR000264        1                5509
                  2                4748
                  3                2090
                  4                2497
                  5                 979
                  6                1206
                  7                 529
                  8                 549
                  9                 729
 API185805        1                1707
                  2                1966
                  3                 744
                  4                1218
                  5                 306
                  6                605
                  7                 138
                  8                 621
                  9                  76
```

dtype: int64

```
        In [18]: type(result)
        Out[18]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I dont need to plot a graph. I just need to subtract the counts from the benford values.

```
   In [22]: result = result.to_frame()

   In [29]: result.columns = ['Count']

   In [32]: result
   Out[32]:
                                     Count
    Send_Agent  Leading_Digit
  ADR000264  1                        5509
             2                        4748
             3                        2090
             4                        2497
             5                        979
             6                        1206
             7                         529
             8                         549
             9                         729
  API185805  1                         1707
             2                         1966
             3                         744
             4                         1218
             5                         306
             6                         605
             7                         138
             8                         621
             9                         76

         In [33]: result['Count'] = (result['Count'])/(result['Count'].sum())

         In [34]: result
         Out[34]:
                                Count
         Send_Agent Leading_Digit
         ADR000264  1                    0.210131
                    2                    0.181104
                    3                    0.079719
                    4                     0.095244
                    5                    0.037342
                    6                     0.046001
                    7                     0.020178
                    8                     0.020941
                    9                     0.027806
         API185805  1                     0.065110
                    2                     0.074990
                    3                     0.028379
                    4                     0.046458
                    5                     0.011672
                    6                     0.023077
                    7                     0.005264
                    8                    0.023687
                    9                     0.002899

    In [35]: result.unstack()
    Out[35]:
                Count                                                    \
     Leading_Digit         1         2         3         4         5        6
    Send_Agent
    ADR000264      0.210131  0.181104  0.079719  0.095244  0.037342      0.046001
    API185805      0.065110  0.074990  0.028379  0.046458  0.011672  0.023077


   Leading_Digit         7         8         9
    Send_Agent
    ADR000264      0.020178  0.020941  0.027806
    API185805      0.005264  0.023687  0.002899

So , benford values for 1 to 9 as follows 
d =  0.30103, 0.176091,  0.124939,  0.09691,  0.0791812,  0.0669468,    0.0579919,  0.0511525,  0.0457575
```

All I need to do is subtract them from result[count].

I am still pretty new to Pandas and Python. So , how do I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool project. I will use a randomly generated dataset for illustration:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
Send_Amount = 10**(np.random.randint(1, 9, 10**6)) * \
                  (np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 10), 
                                    p=np.log10(1+(1/np.arange(1, 10))), 
                                    size=10**6) + 
                   np.random.rand(10**6))
Send_Agent = np.random.choice(['ADR000264', 'API185805'], 10**6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Send_Agent': Send_Agent, 'Send_Amount': Send_Amount.astype(int)})
```

It looks something like this:

```
df.head()
Out[104]: 
  Send_Agent  Send_Amount
0  ADR000264       370394
1  ADR000264    239323923
2  API185805      6364712
3  ADR000264           98
4  ADR000264        56926
```

Now, if you apply that function to the series `Send_Amount`, it will return another series with the leading digits. If you group them first, you need to specify what type of a result you want for each group. That function is not designed to take a group and return a result for that group. It just returns the leading digit for a number.

Instead, to verify [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), you'll need to check the frequency distribution of leading digits. Since you have already created a column for leading digits, now you can groupby Send_Agent and call `value_counts` on that column. In one line, it looks like this:

```
result = df.assign(Leading_Digit = df['Send_Amount'].astype(str).str[0]).groupby('Send_Agent')['Leading_Digit'].value_counts(sort=False)
print(result)
Out[105]: 
Send_Agent  Leading_Digit
ADR000264   1                150522
            2                 87739
            3                 62460
            4                 48204
            5                 39757
            6                 33791
            7                 29024
            8                 25567
            9                 23044
API185805   1                150575
            2                 87994
            3                 62173
            4                 48323
            5                 39452
            6                 33720
            7                 29141
            8                 25538
            9                 22976
Name: Leading_Digit, dtype: int64
```

You could also have done this (after creating the column) with `df.groupby('Send_Agent')['Leading_Digit'].value_counts(sort=False)`. I just did them in one step. Eventually, the distribution will (hopefully) look like this:

```
result.unstack(level=0).plot.bar(subplots=True)
```

[image]

To find the difference between theoretical probabilities and the observed frequencies, you can do this:

```
result = df.assign(Leading_Digit = df['Send_Amount'].astype(str).str[0]).groupby('Send_Agent')['Leading_Digit'].value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True)
```

Note that I passed `normalize=True` so that it calculates proportions rather than frequencies.

Now you can take the difference with:

```
result.unstack(level=0).subtract(np.log10(1+(1/np.arange(1, 10))), axis=0).abs()
Out[16]: 
Send_Agent     ADR000264  API185805
Leading_Digit                      
1               0.000051   0.000185
2               0.000651   0.000065
3               0.000046   0.000566
4               0.000523   0.000243
5               0.000316   0.000260
6               0.000621   0.000508
7               0.000044   0.000303
8               0.000030   0.000065
9               0.000321   0.000204
```

Here, unstack takes the Send_Agent's to the columns. `np.log10(1+(1/np.arange(1, 10)))` calculates the theoretical probabilities. You can pass a previously defined array too. And since we want to subtract the elements row-wise, there is `axis=0` parameter for the `subtract` method. Finally, `.abs()` takes the absolute value of the result.

Comment: . Thanls a ton for your answer. Looks pretty good. I don't need to plot a graph. All I need to do is subtract the count from Benford values.Please see the eidted question with further steps. that need to be done.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by subtract. Can you add a sample of your desired output?

Comment: I want to find the absolute difference between count values and benford values . For instance , for agent ADR000264, the count values are 0.210103,  0.181014,  0.079680,  0.095234,  0.037324,  0.045978, 0.020168 , 0.020930,  0.027793
The Benford values are :
0.30103, 0.176091,  0.124939,  0.09691,  0.0791812,  0.0669468,  0.0579919,  0.0511525,  0.0457575, 0.30103, 0.176091,  0.124939,  0.09691,  0.0791812,  0.0669468,  0.0579919,  0.0511525,  0.0457575. So the absolute difference between the two.

Comment: one last thing..how do I get the sum of the deviations?

Comment: Add `.sum()` at the end (after abs())

Comment: @ayhan...in cases where generated leading digit is 0..this np.log10(1+(1/np.arange(1, 10))) fails and if I make it np.log10(1+(1/np.arange(0, 10))) for it to accept 0 then it fails in scenarios where there are no '0' as leading digit in the dataset. how to make it work uniformly?

Comment: The leading digit should not be zero. How does it happen?

Comment: There are these very very rare scenarios where Send_Amounts are less then a dollar..like 0.35,0.45 etc..

Comment: What value do you want to use for that probability? NaN, 0, something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), because `agg` or `apply` aggregate output:

```
print (df['Send_Amount'].astype(str).str[0].astype(int))
0     3
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     6
5     1
6     7
7     1
8     1
9     5
10    4
11    8
12    9
13    1
Name: Send_Amount, dtype: int32

print (df.groupby('Send_Agent')['Send_Amount'].transform(lambda x: x.astype(str).str[0])
         .astype(int))
0     3
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     6
5     1
6     7
7     1
8     1
9     5
10    4
11    8
12    9
13    1
Name: Send_Amount, dtype: int32
```

If numbers are higher as `9`, use `str[:2]`:

```
print (df['Send_Amount'].astype(str).str[:2].astype(int))
0     36
1     12
2     11
3     12
4     64
5     12
6     77
7     14
8     11
9     56
10    48
11    85
12    94
13    11
Name: Send_Amount, dtype: int32
```

[Transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).